# Magento 2 GD Reindex Error gd.jpeg_ignore_warning

Tags: magento2, php, nginx, apache

I am trying to run reindex in Magento 2.2  apache 2.4 PHP 7.1
Elastic Search installed v 6.4
Search Engine (Amasty ElasticSearch) Tested and Successful.

For this `reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext` running this again gives below error

> Premature end of JPEG file  in
>   vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 65

1. I checked the php.ini file being used for the magento site 
   Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc
   Loaded Configuration File   /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.inI

In researched this error and found other people were given this advice and it fixed the error

"You can the set default value of gd.jpeg_ignore_warning=1 in php.ini

OR

You can set it like this `ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', true);` in your PHP script before calling imagecreatefromjpeg()

After implementing any of the above, GD Library will ignore the error where it use to fail and imagecreatefromjpeg() will return an image resource identifier.

Note: In PHP 7.1.0 the default value of gd.jpeg_ignore_warning has been changed from 0 to 1"

I uncommented the line in my php.ini file

FROM
;gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 0

To 
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 1

Restarted Apache and Nginx

Tried to run the reindex again and the same error

2. Our dedicated server has Multi Php I checked in CLI ssh and it showing the same php.ini is being used by the CLI

I then checked in my mydomain.com/php.info

gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  1 (local value) 1 (master value)

I noticed these are same settings as before I made any changes they were both set to 1  (in the php.ini file mentioned above path it was commented) so where can it be getting this setting from?

Please, can someone help me as I spent over a day looking for a fix on this.

Where else should I be checking or changing this so I can complete the reindex
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Please check **gd.ini** file in mods-available dir

> /etc/php/7.1/mods-available

If **gd.ini** not available then **run** below command

> apt-get install php7.1-gd

will install GD for PHP 7.1

Comment: thanks but I can not find this directory mods-available where else can it be I can not even find /etc/php/    only place i can find any ref  to php 7.1 is /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc

Comment: i checked in WHM and Easy Apache I can see php71-php-gd is installed

Comment: I found gd.ini here [Home]/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d  it was like this ;Enable gd extension module
extension=gd.so  i tried to make it like this   Enable gd extension module

gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 1

extension=gd.so   but I still get the same error

Comment: Did you try this: **apt-get install php7.1-gd**

Comment: Yes tried this apt-get install php7.1-gd  But CLI did not understand it - is it different for linux centos 7  -  secondly as a workaround I went to the file Gd2.php and put @ at the start - which bypass it however after running i got another error Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! in /home/redjohnco/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/                                                                  Image.php on line 420